# looping through and print out (on html) an array of objects with a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var arr=[{a:2, b:3},{a:3, b:4},{a:4,b:5},] 

function printarr(){
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)

}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= printarr();
```

how do I print out each object in the array?
thanks
I would like to write it on an html document, the html is already set

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: JavaScript has no native mechanism for providing output. It depends on a host environment to supply an API. You need to figure out what environment you are running the JS in (is it a browser? is it Node.js? Is it Windows Scripting Host? Is it something else?) and then decide *where* you want to put the output.

Comment: for logging an object in console you have to use the console class and the function console.log() or console.error()

Comment: There are too many concepts missing here for somebody to accurately help you without completely writing the code for you. I suggest doing some research on [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [nested loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and [arrays vs objects](https://frontendmayhem.com/javascript-arrays-objects/) and posting a more complete attempt if you get stuck again.

Comment: thanks,but non of your links work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to assign value of the function call to `innerHTML` you need to return string, empty loop will do nothing. For example this:

```
var arr=[{a:2, b:3},{a:3, b:4},{a:4,b:5},] 

function printarr(){
  var output = '';
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      // \n at the end will not work unless output is pre tag or it have pre css
      output += 'a:' + arr[i].a + ', b: ' + arr[i].b + '<br/>';  
  }
  return output;
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= printarr();
```

instead of accessing `.a` and `.b`, you can also use `JSON.stringify` function on each object:

```
function printarr(){
  var output = '';
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    output += JSON.stringify(arr[i]) + '<br/>';
  }
  return output;
}
```

you can even use it for whole array:

```
function printarr(){
  return JSON.stringify(arr);
}
```

`JSON.stringify` accept also two additional arguments, if you wan to have pretty print (indent) you can use this:

```
function printarr(){
  return JSON.stringify(arr, true, 2); // 2 is number of spaces per indent
}
```

Comment: I wonder why I get downvote this is exactly what OP want/doing assigning function call to `innerHTML` his code have nothing about console.log and console

Comment: hey jcubic, thanks, it worked beautifully. I don't understand also why you got a downvote. I'm new to JS and I've been studying alot I just needed a push here, thanks I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=[{a:2, b:3},{c:3, d:4},{d:4,e:5}] 

function printarr(arr){
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   console.log(arr[i]) // to print whole object
   console.log(arr[i].a) // to print only property a
   console.log(arr[i].b) // to print only property b
  }
} 

printarr(arr);
```

Comment: that gives [object Object] on the html. I would like to print out both the property value pairs.  like a:2 b:3 etc

Comment: try to use console.log(JSON.stringify(arr[i]));

Comment: it depend upon you template rendering engine .. if you are using angular you can use {{objectName}} inside html tag

Comment: thanks but it printed out just the first element in the array with the braces and commas and everything, I just want the property value pairs printed

Comment: because you have different field name for each object... normally in such cases where you are looping data you have consistent data objects.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry, I asked incorrectly, the properties are the same through out the object

Answer (score -3):

Try this out

```
arr.forEach((elem)=>console.log(elem))
```

Answer (score -4):

You are almost there.

```
var arr=[{a:2, b:3},{c:3, d:4},{d:4,e:5},];
function printarr(){
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     Console.Writeline(arr[i].a);
     Console.Writeline(arr[i].b);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Console.Writeline`?! What JS environment is that?

Comment: @AcrobatJava — Your choice of editor is irrelevant unless you are asking how to get output when writing a plugin for it.